# Normal distribution problem with 2 normal distributions?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I have this problem:

> A professor of statistics noticed that the marks in his course are normally distributed. He also noticed that his morning classes average 70% with a standard deviation of 13% on their final exams. His afternoon classes average 79% with a standard deviation of 9%.
>   What is the probability that a randomly selected student in the morning class has a higher final exam mark than a randomly selected student from an afternoon class?

I've been trying to solve this problem myself for quite awhile and not really sure what is wrong with my approach.

I let the morning class = X1 and the afternoon class = X2. So E(X1) = 70, σ(X1) = 13, E(X2) = 79, and σ(X2) = 9. Then I let the variable Y = X1-X2, and since X1 and X2 are both normally distributed, then Y will be as well. So I have the following for Y:

$$E(Y) = E(X_1)-E(X_2) = 70-79 = -9$$
$$σ(Y) = \sqrt{σ(X_1)^2 + σ(X_2)^2} = \sqrt{13^2+9^2} = \sqrt{250}$$

In oder to find the probability that a randmly selected student in the morning class has a higher final exam mark than one from the afternoon class, we want P(X1 > X2) = P(X1 - X2 > 0) = P(Y > 0). So I converted this to z-score...

$$Z = \frac{X-E(Y)}σ = \frac{0-(-9)}{\sqrt{250}} = \frac 9{\sqrt{250}} \approx 0.57$$

So that we are looking for P(Z > 0.57) or 1-P(Z$\leq$0.57).

I looked at my z-score table and found my answer to be **0.2843**, which is marked as wrong. I've tried doing different things for rounding etc., and still can't seem to find the right answer. Any insight is greatly appreciated - maybe I made some dumb error that I can't seem to see. Thank you! :)

Comment: DO NOT ROUND MORE THAN YOU HAVE TO UNTIL THE LAST STEP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is perfectly fine, but you've rounded too much precision off your $z$-score, which is why your answer is off.  The $z$-score is $0.56921$, thus the probability is $0.284607$.

Comment: For some reason we are only allowed to use tables that take a z-score to 2 decimal pts only, and give a probability to 4 decimal points, even though the program is looking for an exact answer :|  Thank you very much!

Comment: @EmmaG. In that case, you will need to use linear interpolation of the table to achieve the necessary precision.  Since $0.56921$ is $0.00921$ away from $0.56$ and $0.00079$ away from $0.57$, you would look up $\Pr[Z \le 0.56] = 0.2877$ and $\Pr[Z \le 0.57] = 0.2843$.  Then you would calculate $$\Pr[Z \le 0.56921] \approx (0.079)(0.2877) + (0.921)(02843) = 0.2846.$$  This gets you the precision you need.